# how best to create a Vue vue-cli app that can handle multiple access rights

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

We have a vue-cli app that will have approximately 5 different access rights. I was thinking of having 5 different builds of our vue-cli script and reconcile on the server and via the API. We obviously don't want an end user snooping through chrome dev tools at the routes.

What strategies have other people used to handle this? We will obviously also be handling authentication on the server.

### edit 1

we will be checking on the server authentication and authorization. The question is about limiting routes snooping on the client side; not a security risk but an unnecessary information leak

Comment: If you've been writing proper secure code, nothing in your client-side routes should pose a security risk. You could open source the whole thing safely.

Comment: Even if you have proper access control layer (ACL) on `vue` part, that's just for the presentation layer, which may conditionally show/hide/provide/deny to see partials of your page but you still need to guard the server side access with some layer.

Comment: there's no concern about people people posting data that will updated the db. We'd rather not have those routes accessible to an end user who might not need them.

Comment: You can even opt in for server side rendering based on access rights with Nuxt.js

Comment: @timpone, worth giving a try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue+acl&rlz=1C5CHFA_enBD695BD695&oq=vue+acl&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j35i39l2.5381j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).